# golang scp file using crypto/ssh

Tags: go, ssh, scp

I'm trying to download a remote file over ssh
The following approach works fine on shell

```
ssh hostname "tar cz /opt/local/folder" > folder.tar.gz
```

However the same approach on golang giving some difference in output artifact size. For example the same folders with pure shell produce artifact gz file 179B and same with go script 178B.
I assume that something has been missed from io.Reader or session got closed earlier. Kindly ask you guys to help.

Here is the example of my script:

```
func executeCmd(cmd, hostname string, config *ssh.ClientConfig, path string) error {
    conn, _ := ssh.Dial("tcp", hostname+":22", config)
    session, err := conn.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to create session: " + err.Error())
    }

    r, _ := session.StdoutPipe()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)

    go func() {
        defer session.Close()

        name := fmt.Sprintf("%s/backup_folder_%v.tar.gz", path, time.Now().Unix())
        file, err := os.OpenFile(name, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0644)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer file.Close()
        for scanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Println(scanner.Bytes())
            if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }

            if _, err = file.Write(scanner.Bytes()); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)

            }
        }
    }()

    if err := session.Run(cmd); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        panic("Failed to run: " + err.Error())
    }

    return nil
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: A scanner is for newline delimited text, don't use it for binary data (it removes the newline characters)

Comment: thanks JimB, can u pls advise what can be used for binary data?

Comment: Also, it's also safer to use something more unique than seconds to create a unique filename, like `ioutil.TempFile` or random strings, since 2 quick runs of your program or simultaneous executions can collide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bufio.Scanner` is for newline delimited text. According to the documentation, the scanner will remove the newline characters, stripping any `10`s out of your binary file.

You don't need a goroutine to do the copy, because you can use `session.Start` to start the process asynchronously.

You probably don't need to use bufio either. You should be using io.Copy to copy the file, which has an internal buffer already on top of any buffering already done in the ssh client itself. If an additional buffer is needed for performance, wrap the session output in a [`bufio.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader)

Finally, you return an error value, so use it rather than panic'ing on regular error conditions.

```
conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", hostname+":22", config)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

session, err := conn.NewSession()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer session.Close()

r, err := session.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

name := fmt.Sprintf("%s/backup_folder_%v.tar.gz", path, time.Now().Unix())
file, err := os.OpenFile(name, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0644)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer file.Close()

if err := session.Start(cmd); err != nil {
    return err
}

n, err := io.Copy(file, r)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if err := session.Wait(); err != nil {
    return err
}

return nil
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it helped me a lot.

Comment: Just a quick question on io.Copy. The reason I use io.Reader is that I need to transfer large tar packages 15-30Gb each, as I understand io.Copy will try to keep it in mem untill it find EOF? Is that right?

Comment: @neveragny: No, I'm not sure what gave you that impression. io.Copy copies directly from src to dst.

Comment: I just ran it and while ssh transfering data, file size is not changing, so since it should keep data somewhere to write it later this place should be mem, isn't it? or it keep it in some cache on FS? (that's just me curious) thx

Comment: @neveragny: you can look at the [`io` package source](https://golang.org/src/io/io.go?#L366) and quickly see that it reads then immediately writes. The writes are buffered by the OS, and won't be written to disk until the file is synced, which is probably not until it's closed.

Comment: The code is no different. I run this script on windows and it downloads a tarball file using my max connection speed around 200~ then I compile go for Linux and run the script and the speed is around 6 - 10~ MB. Takes forever. Where could I start to investigate the problem?

Comment: #Solved If somebody experiences this problem make sure to check network hardware supports more 100 Mb/s.

Answer (score -1):

You can try doing something like this:

```
r, _ := session.StdoutPipe()
reader := bufio.NewReader(r)

go func() {
    defer session.Close()
    // open file etc

    // 10 is the number of bytes you'd like to copy in one write operation
    p := make([]byte, 10)
    for {
        n, err := reader.Read(p)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("err", err)
        }

        if _, err = file.Write(p[:n]); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}()
```

Make sure your goroutines are synchronized properly so output is completeky written to the file.

Comment: 10 isn't a useful size for a buffer, it's much too small, and isn't aligned to any power of 2. You also need to check fro bytes read _before_ checking for EOF so you don't inadvertently truncate the stream.

Comment: Yeah it's more of a placeholder. What would be a good size though?

Comment: io.Copy uses 32k by default. Just use io.Copy (or CopyBuffer if you need a different buffer size) since it will handle various error combinations properly.