# Sending file over SSH in go

Tags: go, ssh

[I found this answer before posting this question but the answer is not clear to me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242598/golang-scp-file-using-crypto-ssh)

Here is the code of the answer:

```
conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", hostname+":22", config)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

session, err := conn.NewSession()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer session.Close()

r, err := session.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

name := fmt.Sprintf("%s/backup_folder_%v.tar.gz", path, time.Now().Unix())
file, err := os.OpenFile(name, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0644)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer file.Close()

if err := session.Start(cmd); err != nil {
    return err
}

n, err := io.Copy(file, r)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if err := session.Wait(); err != nil {
    return err
}

return nil
```

I don't understand relation between the cmd variable and io.Copy, where and how does it know which file to copy.
I like the idea of using io.Copy but i do not know how to create the file via ssh and start sending content to it using io.Copy.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/bramvdbogaerde/go-scp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a minimal example on how to use Go as an `scp` client:

```
config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: "user",
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        ssh.Password("pass"),
    },
    HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
}

client, _ := ssh.Dial("tcp", "remotehost:22", config)
defer client.Close()

session, _ := client.NewSession()
defer session.Close()

file, _ := os.Open("filetocopy")
defer file.Close()
stat, _ := file.Stat()

wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(1)

go func() {
    hostIn, _ := session.StdinPipe()
    defer hostIn.Close()
    fmt.Fprintf(hostIn, "C0664 %d %s\n", stat.Size(), "filecopyname")
    io.Copy(hostIn, file)
    fmt.Fprint(hostIn, "\x00")
    wg.Done()
}()

session.Run("/usr/bin/scp -t /remotedirectory/")
wg.Wait()
```

Note that I have ignored all errors only for conciseness.

1. `session.StdinPipe()` will create a writable pipe for the remote host.
2. `fmt.Fprintf(... "C0664 ...")` will signal the start of a file with `0664` permission, `stat.Size()` size and the remote filename `filecopyname`.
3. `io.Copy(hostIn, file)` will write the contents of `file` into `hostIn`.
4. `fmt.Fprint(hostIn, "\x00")` will signal the end of the file.
5. `session.Run("/usr/bin/scp -qt /remotedirectory/")` will run the scp command.

**Edit**: Added waitgroup per OP's request

Comment: If you don't want to go through the trouble of writing this, there are already packages out there that has this functionality: https://github.com/bramvdbogaerde/go-scp

Comment: I really wanted answer like this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It doesn't really work for me. It creates the file but there is no content inside. I actually realised it's not great to use session with scp within a command. This answer looks more of a copy paste than actual answer. io.Copy does not work. It just finishes because it's inside of the Goroutine otherwise it's left "doing something"

Comment: file with no content?

Comment: io.Copy spins forever

Comment: If you add session.Wait() to not finish before io.Copy finishes it just spins forever and does not send any content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183498/discussion-between-ssemilla-and-howtogo).

Comment: okay, you were right. It works. I made a mistake of using os.OpenFile instead of os.Open and it was the cause of the error i couldn't notice

Comment: what does -t parameter do with scp command? its not within the help, and its inconsistent inside your answer is -qt and -t

Answer (score 10):

You can do it using sftp package as well - "github.com/pkg/sftp"

```golang
func SSHCopyFile(srcPath, dstPath string) error {
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "user",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password("pass"),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }

    client, _ := ssh.Dial("tcp", "remotehost:22", config)
    defer client.Close()


    // open an SFTP session over an existing ssh connection.
    sftp, err := sftp.NewClient(client)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer sftp.Close()

    // Open the source file
    srcFile, err := os.Open(srcPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer srcFile.Close()

    // Create the destination file
    dstFile, err := sftp.Create(dstPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer dstFile.Close()

    // write to file
    if  _, err := dstFile.ReadFrom(srcFile); err!= nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Then call it like

```golang
SSHCopyFile("/path/to/local/file.txt", "/path/on/remote/file.txt")
```

these are the required packages

```
"github.com/pkg/sftp"
"golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
```